# How to replace inner html using returned results from json_encode with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

To be more clear [here is my fiddle for demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dgo88q74/).

I have multiple DIVs with a unique ID like so: desk_85 (the small box you see and the number changes).

```
<div class="desk_box_ver id="desk_85" data-rel="85" style="left:20px;top:1165px;">B20</div>
```

I want my "aht_value" from show_aht.php to replace the number inside every appropriate "desk_#" DIV.

**example of my json_encode result :**

```
[{"username":"HCZR","aht_value":"578","station":"B12"{"username":"FEHER4","aht_value":"703","station":"B20"}]
```

**Problems I want to achieve:**:

I'll use the DIV and VALUES above for this example...

1.Match the station number from the array with the station number from the  desk_# DIV, in other words, compare the "B20" from json result with the "B20" in the DIV.

2. IF they match, replace the inner html from desk_85 with the "aht_value" from the array (so have displaying 278 instead of B20)

If I need to clarify things please tell me.
thanks in advance!

**map.php AJAX**

```
<div id="aht"><!--aht button--> 
    <button id="aht_button">AHT</button>    
</div><!--aht button-->

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#aht').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type:"GET",
                    url : "show_aht.php",
                    data:{  } , // do I need to pass data if im GET ting?
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success : function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                        /*for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                            $("#test_"+i).html(data[i]);    
                        }//end for  
                        */
                      }//end success
                });//end ajax
              });//end click
            });//end rdy
        </script>
```

**show_aht.php - json_encode part**

```
    foreach ($memo as $username => $memodata) {
    if (in_array($username, array_keys($user))) {
    // Match username against the keys of $user (the usernames) 
    $userdata = $user[$username];
    if (is_null($memodata['aht_value'])) {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => 'NA',
                                             'station'  => $userdata['station']
                                            );
    } 
    else {
        $result[] = array( 'username'  => $userdata['username'],
                                             'aht_value' => substr($memodata['aht_value'],0,-3),
                                             'station'   => $userdata['station']
                                            );
    }
    }
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I understand the process:

1. Find all divs with class "desk_box_ver"
2. Loop over the returned list of objects like {"username":"HCZR","aht_value":"578","station":"B12"}
3. For each returned object, loop over the divs from 1. and see the div has a inner HTML matching the object's station property
4. If it does, replace the inner HTML with object's aht_value property.

The desk_# IDs don't actually seem to be used here - is that right?

The Javascript code would be something like:

```
success : function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var allDivs = $('.desk_box_ver');  // 1.
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // 2.
        for (var j = 0; j < allDivs.length; j++) {
            if (allDivs[j].innerHTML === data[i]['station']) { // 3.
                allDivs[j].innerHTML = data[i]['aht_value'];   // 4.
            }
        }
    }
} // end success
```

This isn't a super great way of organizing the code (nested for loops are generally bad, though at smaller sizes might not matter much), but it should do what you need.

With IDs like `desk_B20`, you can do:

```
success : function(data){
    console.log(data);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // loop over results
        var divForResult = $('#desk_' + data[i]['station']); // look for div for this object
        if (divForResult.length) { // if a div was found
            divForResult.html(data[i]['aht_value']); // set inner HTML
        }
    }
} // end success
```

Comment: yes thats exactly it.. however there are multiple DIVs with "desk_box_ver" thats why I mentioned "desk_#" IDs because they are unique. But yes you got the idea of what I want to do.

Comment: what if theres 2 DIVs? I have a while loop in PHP creating those divs with either class name of "desk_box_ver" and "desk_box_hor"

Comment: If you have two different classes for the divs you need to check, you should do `var allDivs = $('.desk_box_ver, .desk_box_hor');`

Comment: oh man thanks a lot was trying to solve this for hours I'm new with AJAX/Jquery.. what would be the difference between **$('.desk_box_ver, .desk_box_hor');**  and **$('.desk_box_ver').add('.desk_box_hor');** wouldnt the loop be going multiple times before it executes on either way? thanks a lot appreciate it

Comment: Looks like `$('.desk_box_ver').add('.desk_box_hor')` and `$('.desk_box_ver, .desk_box_hor')` return the same thing - a set with divs for both classes. But I'd use the latter since it's more standard for DOM queries (you'd use it in CSS and so on).

The loop issue I mentioned is that if you have 100 divs and 100 returned objects and they match exactly, the code would perform 100 divs * 100 objects = 10,000 comparisons where preferably we'd like to have it to compare just 100 times. But it'd be difficult to fix this without significantly rewriting how you're creating the divs.

Comment: hmm.. I see that getting 10 000 comparisons in a AJAX call can actually slow things down in terms of performance. I can put my code where I'm creating the DIVS if you'd like to see. Though its a WHILE loop in PHP and being output in html.

Comment: If you can modify the PHP that generates it, what would help in this case is including the `B20` in a class (e.g. "desk_box_B20") or ID ("desk_B20" instead of "desk_85" - if you don't need the desk_85 in other code) on the div. Then the div can be found directly rather than going through all divs with a common desk_box class.

Comment: what you just said is exactly what I was trying to do with desk_# ID because I thought that going through it that way was a good idea, but now that you mention using "desk_B20" as ID is even better. I will change the PHP script to replace the those values. How will the JS part change in that case? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64816/discussion-between-jarek-piorkowski-and-alda1234).